# Snakemake MissingOutputException latency-wait ignored

Tags: snakemake

I am attempting to run some picard tools metrics collection in snakemake. A --dryrun works fine with no errors. When I actually run the snake file I receive an MissingOutputException for reasons I do not understand.

First here is my rule

```
rule CollectAlignmentSummaryMetrics:
    input:
        "bam_input/final/{sample}/{sample}.ready.bam"
    output:
        "bam_input/final/{sample}/metrics/{reference}/alignment_summary.metrics"
    params:
        reference=config['reference']['file'],
        memory="10240m"
    run:
        "java -Xmx{params.memory} -jar $HOME/software/picard/build/libs/picard.jar CollectAlignmentSummaryMetrics R={params.reference} I={input} O={output}"
```

Now the error.

```
snakemake --latency-wait 120 -s metrics.snake -p
Provided cores: 1
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        38      CollectAlignmentSummaryMetrics
        1       all
        39

rule CollectAlignmentSummaryMetrics:
    input: bam_input/final/TB5173-T14/TB5173-T14.ready.bam
    output: bam_input/final/TB5173-T14/metrics/GRCh37/alignment_summary.metrics
    jobid: 7
    wildcards: reference=GRCh37, sample=TB5173-T14

Error in job CollectAlignmentSummaryMetrics while creating output file bam_input/final/TB5173-T14/metrics/GRCh37/alignment_summary.metrics.
MissingOutputException in line 21 of/home/bwubb/projects/PD1WES/metrics.snake:
Missing files after 5 seconds:
bam_input/final/TB5173-T14/metrics/GRCh37/alignment_summary.metrics
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Will exit after finishing currently running jobs.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

The --latency-wait is completely ignored. I have even tried bumping it up to 84600. If I am to run the intended picard java command, it executes no problem. Ive made several snakemake pipelines without any mysterious issues, so this is driving me quite mad. Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for reporting.

1. It is a bug that latency-wait is not propagated when using the `run` directive. I have fixed that in the master branch.
2. In your rule, you use the `run` directive. After `run`, Snakemake expects plain Python code. You simply provide a string. This means that Python will simply initialize the String and then exit. What you really want here is to use the `shell` directive. See [here](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#rules). By using the `shell` directive, your current problem will be fixed, and you should not be affected by the bug. There is also no need to modify latency-wait. Anyway, the fix for the latency-wait bug will occur in the next release for Snakemake.

Comment: AHHH! I didnt even notice I put **run** instead of **shell**. It was blind to it. Thank you very much!